# pycopg2がインストール出来ない｡

Tags: python, windows, django

DjangoをPostageSQLと使いたいと思い設定して､migrateしたのですが､以下のエラーが出てしまいました｡

**エラー:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\post
gresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 23, in <module>
import psycopg2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", li
ne 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py
", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mod
els.py", line 40, in <module>
class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 122, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 297, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\option
s.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py",
line 40, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", li
ne 242, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", li
ne 108, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\zousan\Documents\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\post
gresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 27, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No m
odule named 'psycopg2'
```

psycopg2 が見つかないので pip を使ってインストールを試みたのですが､以下のエラーがでてできませんでした｡

**エラー:**

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pycopg2
No distributions at all found for pycopg2
```

そこで､このエラーについて調べてのですが､ Unix の回答ばかりで Windows の回答が見つかりませんでした｡
なので Windows での解決方法を教えていただけると幸いです｡

**Settings.py**

```
import os
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGE_CODE, TIME_ZONE
import dj_database_url
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@71lbdkiwo_wf!)h0og^#z022$48#7=_9ldccg^(=zb&219640'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#デバッグモードをするか判定
DEBUG = True
if bool(os.environ.get('LOCAL_DEV', False)):
    DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrapform',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'homesecurity.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'homesecurity.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases
#データベースをどれにするか判定
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
if bool(os.environ.get('LOCAL_DEV', False)):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),   
        }
    }

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: 修正して頂きありがとうございます｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Djangoのエラーでは `psycopg2` で、pip のエラーでは `pycopg2` となっています。
PyPIには `pycopg` というパッケージは登録されていないので、pipでのインストール時にパッケージ名を打ち間違えて、そのようなエラーが出ているのだと思います。

```
pip install psycopg2
```

で再度試してみて下さい。

Comment: `pip install psycopg2`をウインドウズで実行した場合、コンパイラー(minGWとか）が必要でしょうか？

Comment: やってみるのが一番早いと思いますが、必要らしいですね。
http://pythonhosted.org//psycopg2/install.html#install-from-source

正直、これをpipで入れるのは面倒だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ウインドウズのバイナリインストーラは、こちらからダウンロードできます：

http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/